# Converting docx to pdf using LibreOffice library on AWS lambda but unable to convert when trying with different font family other than times roman

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pdf-generation, libreoffice

Converting docx to pdf using LibreOffice library on AWS lambda but unable to convert when trying with different font family other than "times roman" .Please recommend other library instead of installing new fonts for a particular font family

```
#code -

import os
from io import BytesIO
import tarfile
import boto3
import subprocess
import brotli
libre_office_install_dir = '/tmp/instdir'

def load_libre_office():
    if os.path.exists(libre_office_install_dir) and os.path.isdir(libre_office_install_dir):
        print('We have a cached copy of LibreOffice, skipping extraction')
    else:
        print('No cached copy of LibreOffice, extracting tar stream from Brotli file.')
        buffer = BytesIO()
        with open('/opt/lo.tar.br', 'rb') as brotli_file:
            d = brotli.Decompressor()
            while True:
                chunk = brotli_file.read(1024)
                buffer.write(d.decompress(chunk))
                if len(chunk) < 1024:
                    break
            buffer.seek(0)
    print('Extracting tar stream to /tmp for caching.')
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=buffer) as tar:
       tar.extractall('/tmp')
       print('Done caching LibreOffice!')
    return f'{libre_office_install_dir}/program/soffice.bin'
def download_from_s3(bucket, key, download_path):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
def upload_to_s3(file_path, bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3.upload_file(file_path, bucket, key)
def convert_word_to_pdf(soffice_path, word_file_path, output_dir):
    conv_cmd = f"{soffice_path} --headless --norestore --invisible --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --nologo --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir {output_dir} {word_file_path}"
    response = subprocess.run(conv_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if response.returncode != 0:
        response = subprocess.run(conv_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if response.returncode != 0:
            return False
    return True
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = "xxxx"
    key = "xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/SampleDoc.docx"
    key_prefix, base_name = os.path.split(key)
    download_path = f"/tmp/{base_name}"
    output_dir = "/tmp"
    download_from_s3(bucket, key, download_path)
    soffice_path = load_libre_office()
    
    is_converted = convert_word_to_pdf(soffice_path, download_path, output_dir)
    if is_converted:
       file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(base_name)
       upload_to_s3(f"{output_dir}/{file_name}.pdf", bucket, f"    {key_prefix}/{file_name}.pdf")
       return {"response": "file converted to PDF and available at same S3 location of input key"}
    else:
        return {"response": "cannot convert this document to PDF"}
```

Comment: Sharing your code and showing how you're using fonts will help others. It might not be library issue and some configuration issue.